# Shell cutting off one element in arglist

Tags: c++, shell, parsing

I am making a shell in c++ and i have some problems.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

std::vector<char *> Split(std::string input);
void Execute(const char *command, char *arglist[]);
bool BuiltInCom(const char *command, char *arglist[]);
char** conv(std::vector<char *> source);
int main() {
  while (1) {
    // Takes input and splits it by space
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "$: ";
    getline(std::cin, input);
    std::vector<char *> parsed_string = Split(input);
    // Splits parsed_string into command and arglist
    const char * com = parsed_string.front();
    parsed_string.erase(parsed_string.begin());
    char ** arglist = parsed_string.data();
    // Prints arglist for debugging purposes
    std::cout << "Arglist: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arglist)/sizeof(arglist[0]); i++) std::cout << arglist[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // Checks if it is a built in command and if not, execute it
    if(BuiltInCom(com, arglist) == 0){
        Execute(com, arglist);
    }
  }
}

std::vector<char*> Split(std::string input) {
  std::vector<char*> ret;
  std::istringstream f(input);
  std::string s;
  while (getline(f, s, ' ')) {
    char* buf = new char[strlen(s.c_str()) + 1];
    strcpy(buf, s.c_str());
    ret.push_back(buf);
  }
  return ret;
}

void Execute(const char *command, char *arglist[]) {
  pid_t pid;
  //Creates a new proccess
  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: Cannot create new process" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    //Executes the command
    if (execvp(command, arglist) < 0) {
      std::cout << "Could not execute command" << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    } else {
      sleep(2);
    }
  }
  //Waits for command to finish
  if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) != pid) {
    std::cout << "Error: waitpid()";
    exit(-1);
  }
}

bool BuiltInCom(const char *command, char ** arglist){
  if(strcmp(command, "quit") == 0){
    exit(0);
  } else if(strcmp(command, "cd") == 0){
    if(chdir((const char*) arglist) < 0){
      for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arglist)/sizeof(arglist[0]); i++) std::cout << arglist[i];
      std::cout << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Changing dir failed" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    return 1;
  }
    return 0;
}

}
```

The problem with this code is that when I execute `arglist`, it seems to chop off the first element off `arglist` when executing.

Example:
If I inputted `ls -a -l`, arglist would equal `-a, -l`. Then when arglist is executed, it only executes `-l`. I cannot debug this, because it forks off into a new proccess.

Comment: Why  not use `string` everywhere instead of `char*`?

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code and see what happens?

Comment: "_I cannot debug this, because it forks off into a new proccess_" - If that's a problem, why not temprarilly disable the `fork()`ing? Anyway, you must be able to print the content of `arglist` _before_ the `fork()` to verify that it's correct, right?

Comment: It executes fine for me. The only problem is with the printing, which happens due to the reason @TedLyngmo mentioned.

Comment: Was this line uncommented when you tested?: `//parsed_string.erase(parsed_string.begin());`

Comment: @Tomer Try executing the code with the `parsed_string.erase(parsed_string.begin());` uncommented.

Comment: @rici It was uncommented

Comment: I guess that explains why the first element was deleted. You deleted it.

Comment: Also, please note that the `argv` array you pass to `execvp` must be termnated with a `NULL`. The `data` member from `std:vector` does not meet this requirement.

Comment: And in case you still have doubts, check what [man exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) says about the first element of `argv`.